# Get associated product full size image

Tags: magento-1.8, product, image

Hi this is my code in view.phtml,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    var assocIMG =  // Added  - Removed { here, causes issues with other scripts when not working with a configurable product.
<?php
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
        echo "{";
        $associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
        foreach ($associated_products as $assoc)
            $dados[] = $assoc->getId().":'".($assoc->image == "no_selection" || $assoc->image == "" ? $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_product->image)->resize(365,400) : $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($assoc, 'image', $assoc->image)->resize(365,400))."'";
    } else {
        $dados[] =  "''";
    }
    echo implode(',', $dados );     
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
        echo "}";
    }
    ?>
</script>
```

And i'n my configurable.js,

```
var productNo = intersect(selectedAssocProducts) || selectedAssocProducts[attributeId][0];
alert(assocIMG[productNo]);
```

Giving me `http://localhost/vinoth/liveinnew/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/365x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/S/L/SLP-DB-1_24.jpg`

IS there any way to get full image of the product instead of resized ?

I've tried removing resizing condition in view.phtml but it's affetcing all.

Did anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full size image like this:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($assoc, 'image', $assoc->image).
```

Place this where you need it.

Comment: that's affecting all images. I need both full image and re-sized image. Because for product zoom i need full image.

Comment: @Vinoth. Edited my answer.